# How do I get started with Hamlet.coffee?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I'd like to be able to quickly and easily get up and running with Hamlet in node.js or the browser.

Where are some good resources for getting started?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [README](https://github.com/dr-coffee-labs/hamlet/blob/master/README.md)

#### Using Node.js

Install the command line Hamlet compiler

```
npm install hamlet-cli
```

Compile your templates and export them

```
node_modules/.bin/hamlet -d templates
```

Add hamlet-runtime to your package.json

```
npm install --save-dev hamlet-runtime
```

To use the templates in a Node.js style project built with [browserify](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify) you can require them normally.

```
// main.js
mainTemplate = require("./templates/main");

document.body.appendChild(mainTemplate(data));
```

Now use browserify to build the file you'll serve on your page.

```
browserify main.js > build.js
```

**Additional Resources**

To get started I recommend the getting started section of the [official readme](https://github.com/dr-coffee-labs/hamlet#getting-started)

For general help or discussion you can talk on the [Hamlet.Coffee google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/hamletcoffee)

Specific questions about using Hamlet.coffee can be asked here on SO or on the google group.

Issues should be opened on the git repo https://github.com/dr-coffee-labs/hamlet/issues?state=open